# Array being incorrectly overwritten using index of non-zero values

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array of numbers that follows a poisson distribution where I want to overwrite each nonzero value by itself multiplied by some random number

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

jumps = stats.poisson(mu=0.05).rvs(200) # generate 200 random poisson numbers
idx = np.where(jumps!=0)[0] # get the index where jumps is non zero
for i in idx:
    # want to overwrite the i'th index in jumps with itself
    # multiplied by a random float
    jumps[i] = jumps[i]*np.random.normal()

print(jumps) # we get only 0,-1,1
>>> [0 0 -1 ....
     0 0 0]
```

Even if I include a temporary variable, I still only get 0,-1,1's

```
for i in idx:
    # want to overwrite the i'th index in jumps with itself
    # multiplied by a random float
    tmp = jumps[i]*np.random.normal()
    jumps[i] = tmp

print(jumps) # we still get only 0,-1,1
>>> [0 0 -1 ....
     0 0 0]
```

If you print `tmp` out at each iteration, you will see it works fine. But for some reason, `jumps[i]` is not being overwritten correctly.

What is going on here?

Comment: What's the `dtype` of `jumps`?

Comment: @ThomasKühn it seems they were ints when initialised - if I change the dtype to float it works :) Thanks!